# How to enable c# 7 features on Unity3D projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, project, c#-7.0

I wrote a new method in my Unity3D project (using Visual Studio 2017), and for that method I need C# 7 or greater. So I followed the instructions in [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enabling-c-sharp-7-compilation-with-visual-studio-2017/).

Now, when I try to open the project's properties, Visual Studio opens it, but then it suddenly closes right after opening. Now I can't even open project's properties.

This is how it looks:

[image: gif]

Why am I getting the first and third errors? (the ones I showed in the gif)

Comment: You can directly check `.csproj` and it properties in any text redactor and fix they.

Comment: @maccettura: Not officially, but since mono support some of its features, it is indeed possible to enable the "experimental" use of C# 7.0. I did it myself and it is working perfectly. C# 6 vs. C# 7 differ like day and night regarding some code readability features and tuples.

Comment: The Roslyn compiler is now supported in **Unity 2018.3**, which allows you to use the latest C# 7 features! See: [Unity's 2018.3 beta new features](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/13/unity-2018-3-beta-get-early-access-now)

Comment: The properties not opening up is not a bug.  It's a setting you can toggle on/off.  To enable accessing properties in a Unity project navigate to:
`tools->options->tools for unity->general`
Under the "Miscellaneous" heading, there is an "Acces to project properties" flag.  Set that to true, and restart VS.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT**

The Roslyn compiler is now supported in **Unity 2018.3**, which allows you to use the latest C# 7 features!

See: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/13/unity-2018-3-beta-get-early-access-now/

---

**For Unity3D < 2018.3.***

I will tell you how I have enabled C# 7.3 in Unity3D projects (although some of its features can't be compiled yet). But beware: this method is a hack! It is a premature and experimental usage of C# 7 in Unity.

If you follow the instructions below, I believe you may be able to easily track down the issue, given that in the case of your question it is quite difficult to provide a full MCVE for the SO community. But I believe that what you actually are trying to achieve is enabling C# 7 for Unity, and not solve the bizarre bug in the project properties window.

Before proceeding, I would recommend completely reinstalling Visual Studio 2017 and Unity3D, just to make sure that you are not having any issue related to a bad installation. Always download Unity directly from Unity's webpage instead of using Viual Studio's Installer, so you can get the latest version available.

**Enabling C# 7 in Unity 3D projects (tested on Unity3D v.2018.2.10f, VS 2017 v.15.8.5)**

1. First create a new fresh empty project.
2. Go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player`, find the `Other Settings` section, then under `Configuration` / `Scripting Runtime Version` choose `.NET 4.x Equivalent`.
3. We want to tell mcs.exe to process the C# code using the new "experimental" features of C# 7. For that, just create the file `mcs.rsp` inside your Assets folder. Edit it and write the this line inside it:

   ```
   -langversion:experimental
   ```
4. Now, create a new folder named `Editor` inside your `Assets` folder. Any scripts added to this folder will make Unity create a `*.Editor.csproj` project file, which holds contain scripts aimed to modify the Unity Editor.
5. We need to tell Visual Studio that your project supports the C# 7.3 language. This doesn't mean that Unity will be able to compile all features of C# 7.3, but at least Visual Studio will not bitch about the features you are trying to use experimentally.

   However if you edit a `csproj` file directly, Unity will automatically overwrite it at some point (Unity always auto-generate project and solution files). So what you can do is to install a hook which is called when the project file is auto-generated, so you can open the project file yourself and add your customization to it (your customizations are not limited just to changing the language version: you could do more stuff, but you must understand what you are doing here).

   For this purpose, place the following script inside the `Editor` folder:

   ```
   #if ENABLE_VSTU

   using SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge;
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Xml.Linq;
   using UnityEditor;
   using UnityEngine;

   [InitializeOnLoad]
   public class ProjectFilesGeneration
   {
       private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
       {
           public override Encoding Encoding
           {
               get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
           }
       }

       static ProjectFilesGeneration()
       {
           ProjectFilesGenerator.ProjectFileGeneration += (string name, string content) =>
           {
               // Ignore projects you do not want to edit here:
               if (name.EndsWith("Editor.csproj", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return content;

               Debug.Log($"CUSTOMIZING PROJECT FILE: '{name}'");

               // Load csproj file:
               XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
               XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(content);

               // Find all PropertyGroups with Condition defining a Configuration and a Platform:
               XElement[] nodes = xml.Descendants()
                   .Where(child =>
                       child.Name.LocalName == "PropertyGroup"
                       && (child.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.Name.LocalName == "Condition")?.Value.Contains("'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'") ?? false)
                   )
                   .ToArray();

               // Add <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion> to these PropertyGroups:
               foreach (XElement node in nodes)
                   node.Add(new XElement(ns + "LangVersion", "7.3"));

               // Write to the csproj file:
               using (Utf8StringWriter str = new Utf8StringWriter())
               {
                   xml.Save(str);
                   return str.ToString();
               }
           };
       }
   }

   #endif
   ```

If you want to fully understand what has changed in your project file, just use any diff tool, to compare the previous version and the new version of the `csproj` file. The hack above basically does something similar to the link you've posted when changing the language version, except that it does that every time Unity auto-generates the project file. Microsoft also provides plenty of documentation on the definitions inside `csproj` files.

Comment: Following what you said, I get this error: Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS1617: Invalid option 'experimental' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.

Comment: What version of Unity are you running?

Comment: I'm running Unity 2018.3.9f1

Comment: In this case you are running a version of Unity which already supports Roslyn compiler. If you read the answer carefully, the actions you have to take are for versions of Unity -UNDER- 2018.3, which is not your case. Just be sure you have correctly set the following settings in Unity: Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings->Configuration, there you must set: `Scripting Runtime Version = .NET 4.x`, `Scripting Backend = Mono`, `Api Compatibility Level = .NET 4.x`. As a side note, I have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition installed on my machine too, which I use for script editing.

Answer (score 0):

The properties window not opening sounds like some issue with your installation of Visual Studio (which I can't give much advice on)

For the coding errors, it looks like you're trying to declare a method inside another method (which is quite odd):

```
void Update() {
    ...
    public void Method1();
}
```

I *imagine* that's not your intention. It's complaining because the version of C# you're compiling in doesn't support that (and local methods in C#7 can't be marked `public` in any case). It's also complaining because your method isn't abstract (or extern) but doesn't have a body, which C# doesn't allow. Is this what you meant?

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) // Note no ; here!
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }
}

public void Method1() {
    // Some code
}
```

ALSO you have an erroneous `;` after your `if ()` statement in line 15. That will cause the `GetComponent<Renderer>` line (line 17) to *always* be run, not just if the condition is true. Again, this is probably not what you intended I imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, I'm just a starter so I don't know about all of my faults or what I'm doing in general, It's weird for me because I'm learning c# from unity and sololearn at the same time and unity did pretty much what I did, but I didn't mean to make a method inside another one, how do seperate them?

Comment: You need to move the `public void Method1()` declaration _outside_ of the curly brakcets (`{}`) of the `Update()` method - similarly to how I've given in my code example.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to show the exact code you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Unity (you mention it in your post).  I cannot tell by your gif because its like 4 pixels wide.

If you are indeed using Unity, you will be unable to use C# 7 features yet.  They've only just allowed experimental support for C# 6 (see [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/11/introducing-unity-2017/)).

Unfortunately you are out of luck if you want to use C# 7 in Unity *right now*.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, Yea I don't know why the gif is looking so small.
isn't method something that is used alot and needed? how can I make a game without it? and how did he use it here?
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/variables-and-functions?playlist=17117
(go to about the end of the video)