# Can't find syntax error anywhere in C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I've been working on a C# script in unity governing 'units' and in short, the compiler is telling me the '(' is unexpected in my integer function - 20th line in the pasted code below - before 'int cost' and I just can't find the issue with my script anywhere. If I remove the whole function there are no errors and it compiles successfully so I'm 99% sure the issue lies in the function itself. Apologies for the indentation, new to StackOverflow and bad at adding code onto here!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Iska.CNC.Units
{

public class UnitHandler : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static UnitHandler instance;

    [SerializeField]
    private BasicUnit Pitbull, RaiderBuggy;

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public (int cost, int attack, int attackRange, int health, int tier) GetBasicUnitStats(string type)
    {
        BasicUnit unit;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Pitbull":
                unit = Pitbull;
                break;
            case "RaiderBuggy":
                unit = RaiderBuggy;
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Error - unit cannot be found or does not exist");
                return (0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0);
        }
        return (unit.cost, unit.attack, unit.attackRange, unit.health, unit.tier);
    }

    public void SetBasicUnitStats(Transform type)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in type) 
        {
            foreach (Transform unit in child) 
            {
                string unitName = child.name.Substring (0, child.name.Length - 1).ToLower ();
                var stats = GetBasicUnitStats (unitName);
                Player.PlayerUnit pU;

                if (type == Iska.CNC.Player.PlayerManager.instance.playerUnits) 
                {
                    pU = unit.GetComponent<Player.PlayerUnit> ();
                    //set unit stats in each unit
                    pU.cost = stats.cost;
                    pU.attack = stats.attack;
                    pU.attackRange = stats.attackRange;
                    pU.health = stats.health;
                    pU.tier = stats.tier;
                } 
                else if (type == Iska.CNC.Player.PlayerManager.instance.enemyUnits) 
                {
                    //set enemy stats
                }
                //if we have any upgrades or buffs, add them now
                //add upgrades to unit stats
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This [tuple syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples-and-discards) require you to [enable C# 7 in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45578298/1997232).

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr that solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can do it with

```
public Tuple<int, int, int, int> GetBasicUnitStats (string type)
{
    BasicUnit unit;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Pitbull":
            unit = Pitbull;
            break;
        case "RaiderBuggy":
            unit = RaiderBuggy;
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Error - unit cannot be found or does not exist");
            return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0);
    }

    return Tuple.Create(unit.cost, unit.attack, unit.attackRange, unit.health, unit.tier);
}
```